# Image when Hovered appears some more images (sort of gallery) Html css Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hover

I have this problem where I have set an image to display another image when the mouse hovers over, however the first image still appears and the new one doesn't change height and width and overlaps the other one. I'm still pretty new to HTML/CSS so I may have missed something simple.Here is sample code:

```
<img src="LibraryTransparent.png" id="Library" />
<style>
#Library {
    height: 70px;
    width: 120px;
}

#Library:hover {
    background-image: url('LibraryHoverTrans.png');
    height: 70px;
    width: 120px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: wellcome to SO please add your code and what you tried so far

Comment: SO it's not a free code service. Please show your effort and share some code explaining where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is too much, but this works:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/animals" alt="dog" />
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/people" alt="people" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.container:hover img:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.container img:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.container img:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

See it live Here: https://jsfiddle.net/billy_farroll/ajy5bm5f/